# Passing control from html to android to call an android method

Tags: android, html

I am a total newbie at android (as well as this is my first post on StackOverflow) and I was wondering if there is a way of passing control from a web view displaying HTML to the actual android code. To make it a little more clear:

Suppose I have a HTML code that I am displaying in the web view in android, now I click the submit button (which is in the HTML page), is there a way to use that click to call a method in the android code?

A very high level view can be something like

if(Submit is clicked){ //submit would be the submit button in the html page

call xyz(); //xyz would be the android method

}

I would really appreciate it if you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).
There is a simple example there that should kick you off.

Javascript is the word of the day.

Comment: oooh! did not look at this while going through WebView documentation. I ll check it out. thanks!

Comment: ah just checked it out, looks like this is almost what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`addJavaScriptInterface()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to put a reference in the Javascript environment to some Java object.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb1) demonstrating this, to allow a page in a `WebView` to retrieve a location from the activity hosting the `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView `addJavascriptInterface` to export your method to the HTML page, here is a relevant snippet:

```
WebViewVariable.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(context), "Android");
```

Here is the code for `MyJavaScriptInterface` :

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Context localContext;

    public MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        localContext = ctx;
    }


    public void pageReady() {
        // do your work here
    }
}
```

You can now call the above class's method `pageReady()` from your HTML page like this `Android.pageReady()`. Remember though that you can only pass primitive data types (If I remember correctly).

Hope it helps